# Serial Key Generation and Validation

Tags: python

I'm toying around with writing creating a serial code generator/validator, but I can't seem to get how to do a proper check.

Here's my generator code:

```
# Serial generator

# Create sequences from which random.choice can choose
Sequence_A = 'ABCDEF'
Sequence_B = 'UVWQYZ'
Sequence_C = 'NOPQRS'
Sequence_D = 'MARTIN'

import random

# Generate a series of random numbers and Letters to later concatenate into a pass code
First = str(random.randint(1,5))
Second = str(random.choice(Sequence_A))
Third = str(random.randint(6,9))
Fourth = str(random.choice(Sequence_B))
Fifth = str(random.randint(0,2))
Sixth = str(random.choice(Sequence_C))
Seventh = str(random.randint(7,8))
Eighth = str(random.choice(Sequence_D))
Ninth = str(random.randint(3,5))


serial = First+Second+Third+Fourth+Fifth+Sixth+Seventh+Eighth+Ninth

print serial
```

I'd like to make a universal check so that my validation code will accept any key generated by this.

My intuition was to create checks like this:

```
serial_check = raw_input("Please enter your serial code: ")

# create a control object for while loop
control = True

# Break up user input into list that can be analyzed individually
serial_list = list(serial_check)    

while control:
    if serial_list[0] == range(1,5):
        pass
    elif serial_list[0] != range(1,5):
        control = False

    if serial_list[1] == random.choice('ABCDEF'):
        pass
    elif serial_list[1] != random.choice('ABCDEF'):
        control = False
# and so on until the final, where, if valid, I would print that the key is valid.

if control == False:
      print "Invalid Serial Code"
```

I'm well aware that the second type of check won't work at all, but it's a place holder because I've got no idea how to check that.

But I thought the method for checking numbers would work, but it doesn't either.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `range(1, 5)' creates a list of numbers from 1 to 4. So in your first test, you're asking whether the first character in your serial number is equal to that list:

```
"1" == [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Probably not...

What you probably want to know is whether a digit is *in* the range (i.e. from 1 to 5, I assume, not 1 to 4).

Your other hurdle is that the first character of the serial is a string, not an integer, so you would want to take the `int()` of the first character. But that will raise an exception if it's not a digit. So you must first test to make sure it's a digit:

```
if serial_list[0].isdigit() and int(serial_list[0]) in range(1, 6):
```

Don't worry, if it's not a digit, Python won't even try to evaluate the part after `and`. This is called short-circuiting.

However, I would not recommend doing it this way. Instead, simply check to make sure it is at least "1" and no more than "5", like this:

```
if "1" <= serial_list <= "5":
```

You can do the same thing with each of your tests, varying only what you're checking.

Also, you don't need to convert the serial number to a list. `serial_check` is a string and accessing strings by index is perfectly acceptable.

And finally, there's this pattern going on in your code:

```
if thing == other:
   pass
elif thing != other:
   (do something)
```

First, because the conditions you are testing are logical opposites, you don't need `elif thing != other` -- you can just say `else`, which *means* "whatever wasn't matched by any `if` condition."

```
if thing == other:
   pass
else:
   (do something)
```

But if you're just going to `pass` when the condition is met, why not just test the opposite condition to begin with? You clearly know how to write it 'cause you were putting it in the `elif`. Put it right in the `if` instead!

```
if thing != other:
    (do something)
```

Yes, each of your `if` statements can easily be cut in half.  In the example I gave you for checking the character range, probably the easiest way to do it is using `not`:

```
if not ("1" <= serial_list <= "5"):
```

Comment: Thanks! Y'know I was starting to think that I should just pass the initial conditions, but I wanted to leave it in - not sure why now.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your python, I'm guessing that when your wrote this:

```
if serial_list[0] == range(1,5):
```

You probably meant this:

```
if 1 <= serial_list[0] <= 5:
```

And when you wrote this:

```
if serial_list[1] == random.choice('ABCDEF'):
```

You probably meant this:

```
if serial_list[1] in 'ABCDEF':
```

There are various other problems with your code, but I'm sure you'll improve it as you learn python.

At a higher level, you seem to be trying to build something like a software activation code generator/validator.  You should know that just generating a string of pseudo-random characters and later checking that each is in range is an extremely weak form of validation.  If you want to prevent forgeries, I would suggest learning about HMAC (if you're validating on a secure server) or public key cryptography (if you're validating on a user's computer) and incorporating that into your design.  There are libraries available for python that can handle either approach.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This isn't for anything real, I was curious as to how one would go about making something like a real serial generator and wanted to give it a shot myself and this is what I cam up with. Thanks again.

Comment: Sure.  If you don't intend to ask specific question or to accept an answer, you might want to make it a wiki next time.